# AC measurement in a circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, measurement, spice, transfer-function, integrator

I used the spice language to build an integrator op-amp, and one of the questions I had to address is to run an AC analysis on it.
long story short- by looking at the transfer function of an integrator, I imagined I would get a negative voltage, but I got a positive one. Someone explained that since it's AC measurement, it only measures the amplitude and thus I don't need to actually get negative values. Can you please explain why this is true? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it isn't true that AC simulation only returns positive values.

The input to an AC analysis is a sine wave with a given amplitude and phase. The output again is a sine wave with an amplitude and phase determined by the transfer function of the system.

So the result consists of two values which are usually computed as a complex number. The representation often consists of the magnitude and the phase, since they are easier to work with than the real and imaginary part.

In order to see if a value is negative, it is therefore also required to check the phase. For a negative result an additional phase shift (relative to the input signal) of 180 degrees should occur.

Comment: If you are familiar with such a measurement under the integrator condition, does that mean the values I received are the magnitude, and the minus sign on the integrator transfer function could be the negative phase?

Comment: Most likely, yes. You will have to check magnitude and phase.